# Max-Min distance calculation

Tags: matlab, cluster-computing, distance

I have  used the Max-Min distance measurement on my data, but iam getting an error is Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

the code that i used is :

```
clc;
clear all;
close all; 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
numRows = 100;
A = rand(numRows, 2);      %// Example of input matrix
cent= [ 2.2  3.1; 4.5 5.1];
d= [];
sizeX = size(A,1);
numofC = size(cent,1);

for  i = 1 : sizeX
  for j = 1:numofC
    A= max(cent(j,:),A(i,:));
    B = min(cent(j,:),A(i,:));
  end 
    dist(i)= sum(B)/sum(A)   
 end
```

any help please

Comment: You should probably use `numel` rather than `size` since your inputs are likely row vectors and their `size` in the first dimension is going to be 1. Also, you're only considering the last iteration of the loop since you aren't storing `A` and `B`. I can't really offer a solution because it's not clear what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: What wrong result? Are you getting an incorrect number? Are you getting cat pictures everywhere? Please be more specific on your problem.

Comment: I have change the code ,  the error is iam not getting any result , it is 0,1

Comment: @Suever the size will return 100 sizeX = size(A,1);  it is not 1 ??

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because although you have your input matrix `A` you are trying to assign `max(cent(j,:),A(i,:))` to the same variable `A` thereby overwriting the contents. A subsequent call of `A` in the loop will try to call an element which you overwrote the first time passing through the loop.

I made some changes from your code; for e.g. you also have no matrix named `dist`.

```
clc;
clear;
close all; 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
numRows = 100;
A = rand(numRows, 2);      %// Example of input matrix
cent= [ 2.2  3.1; 4.5 5.1];
sizeX = size(A,1);
numofC = size(cent,1);
dist= zeros(numRows,1);


for  i = 1 : sizeX
    for j = 1:numofC
        X = max(cent(j,:),A(i,:));
        Y = min(cent(j,:),A(i,:));
        dist(i)= sum(X)/sum(Y)   
    end
end
```